# The fragment does not update the content of the editext

Tags: android, android-edittext, fragment

I have 1 fragment.

```
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment 

    EditText matricula;

    public LoginFragment() {

    }

    public static LoginFragment newInstace(String param1, String param2){
        LoginFragment fragment = new LoginFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
        matricula = v.findViewById(R.id.matricula);
        final Button ingresar = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.ingresar);

       ingresar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
               Toast.makeText(getActivity(), matricula.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
       });
        return v;
            }
```

and my mainActivity

```
public class MainActivity {
LoginFragment loginFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        loginFragment = new LoginFragment();
      getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.interfaceSesion,loginFragment).commit();
    }
}
```

But when I click on the "Ingresar" button, the Toast throws me the start value of the EditText
And I change the text
[image]

Here XLM Fragment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/interfaceSesion"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".LoginFragment">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/matricula"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/matricula"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="5"
        android:text="@string/asd"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.144" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ingresar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ingresar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/password"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.095" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

f someone needs more information, do not hesitate to contact me, make several days that I can not solve it. I would really appreciate it

Comment: please show us your xml code of fragment

Comment: Ready, updated !

Comment: When you kill the application and start again then does it occurs or if you apply changes from Android Studio this occurs?because from my side it is working fine.Might be you have just applied changes from android studio just because of that it is showing pre filled characters only.

Comment: yes, i redid the project completely and I walked perfectly, I really appreciate your time, I can continue working.